# How can I store a bunch of double in a single double?

Tags: java

I edited my post.
            :: New logic problem, everytime I input only 1 integer the += only prints 0.

```
        System.out.print("\nEnter the property code: ");
                        sPropertyCode = input.next();
                        bError = false; //set to false 
                        dTotalCommission += dCommissionRate;
                        dTotalSales += dSellPrice;

    if (sPropertyCode.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))//if r or R dRate will store 7,...perform calculation for dCommissionRate
                    {
                        dRate = 7;
                        dCommissionRate = dSellPrice * (dRate/100);
                        System.out.print("Total commission on this property is $" +dCommissionRate);
                    } //this works and prints the calculated amount of rate but when it is going to the last line....


if (sYesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
            {
                System.out.println(sApplicationReport);//prints the Summary Report
                System.out.println ("----------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println ("Total property sales: $" + dTotalSales);//all the stored values for dSellPrice will be added and printed
                System.out.println("Total Commissions: $"+ dTotalCommission);//This part only prints 0.00 instead of the calcuated dCommissionRate
                break;
            }
```

Comment: Did you try _running_ your program?

Comment: It won't allow you? What does it say?

Comment: I havent tried to put the dTotalPrice += dSellPrice but the whole program works but it only calculates the later input.  I used do while loop

Comment: Overwrite the variable or try an array maybe?

Comment: dTotalPrice += dSellPrice is addition, try an array, or post some code ...

Comment: I am sorry. I tried to copy and paste it and it said that my post contains only codew

Comment: ok i will try to post my code

Comment: it wont allow me to post the rest

Comment: Thanks guys, the variables that I just put was just wrong. The += works.  I really appreciated the quick responses. It was like so fast! I have done my assignment now. thanks evertyone!you guys are awesome!

Answer (score 3):

```
dTotalPrice += dSellPrice
```

means : `dTotalPrice = dTotalPrice + dSellPrice`

But if you want to store 10000 and 20000 in a single variable , you can use an **arrayList** :

**Example :**

```
 ArrayList<Double> myValues = new ArrayList<Double>();
 myValues.add(10000 );
 myValues.add(200O00 );
// etc.
```

If you want to show them :

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i < myValues.size(); i++){
    Double mySingleValue = myValues.get(i);
    System.out.println(mySingleValue.toString());
 }
```

Comment: hm yea, so how can I make dSellPrice add to the new dSellPrice and store it in dTotalPrice?

Comment: What if I will enter 100 variables? does it mean I have to put 100 myValues.add?

Comment: if you have a do while or a for loop , you can just write **myValues.add(value );**

Answer (score 2):

Hm. It's kind of hard to follow your thinking, but here is my best shot.

Your code here (dTotalPrice += dSellPrice) Will add the value of dSellPrice to dTotalPrice.

aside from a semicolon you aren't missing anything.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to store multiple doubles in a single double variable, why not try and store your multiple doubles in an array? Therefore you could store your multiple number values in this array and then pick out the ones you want.

Answer (score 0):

You'd just reassign the variable. No problem.

Try it!

```
double dada = 10.7;

/* run jump play */

dada = 3.141592653589;
```

However, what makes more sense is to use an array.

declare a double array -

```
double[] myNumbers = {28.3, 21.2};
```